# unban based on reason discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

so my discord server got hacked and everyone got banned with "gotcha" reason
is there a way to make this code read this reason and unban everyone that has it?
if it's not a big problem can it send this unbanned nicks or id's in the  channel?

```
import discord

from discord.ext import commands


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', intents=intents)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
print('TO PRONTO FDP')

@bot.command()
async def pronto(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Esperando...")

@bot.command()
async def massunban(ctx):
    banlist = await ctx.guild.bans()
    for users in banlist:
        try:
            await ctx.guild.unban(user=users.user)
            await ctx.channel.send(f"UNBANNED: **{users.user}**")
        except:
            pass
            
    await ctx.channel.send(f"Finalizado")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [discord.py 1.7.3 (stable)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)

```
@bot.command()
async def massunban(ctx: commands.Context):
    bans = await ctx.guild.bans()   # list of discord.BanEntry

    for ban_entry in bans:
        await ctx.guild.unban(user=ban_entry.user)

    await ctx.send("Done!")
```

###### References:

- [`discord.Guild.bans`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=unban#discord.Guild.bans)
- [`discord.BanEntry`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20guild#discord.BanEntry)
- [`discord.Guild.unban`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20guild#discord.Guild.unban)

---

For [discord.py 2.0 (latest)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

```
@bot.command()
async def massunban(ctx: commands.Context):
    # Because of a change in Discord's API,
    # discord.Guild.bans() returns now a paginated iterator

    # Flattening into a list
    bans = [ban_entry async for ban_entry in ctx.guild.bans()]   # list of discord.BanEntry
    
    for ban_entry in bans:
        await ctx.guild.unban(user=ban_entry.user)

    await ctx.send("Done!")
```

###### References:

- [`discord.Guild.bans`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20guild#discord.Guild.bans)
- [`discord.BanEntry`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20guild#discord.BanEntry)
- [`discord.Guild.unban`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20guild#discord.Guild.unban)

Answer (score -1):

i solved it

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', intents=intents)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('ready to go')

@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    await ctx.send("!start")

@bot.command()
async def start(ctx):

    reason = "Zardex V3"
    reason2 = "Zardex v3"
    reason3 = "zardex v3"
    reason4 = None

    await ctx.channel.send(f"*Loading...*")
    print('Loading...')
    banlist = await ctx.guild.bans()
    for users in banlist:

        if (reason==users.reason):
            
            try:
                await ctx.guild.unban(user=users.user)
                await ctx.channel.send(f"Unbanned: **{users.user}** Reason: **{users.reason}**")

            except:
                pass
        
        if (reason2==users.reason):
            
            try:
                await ctx.guild.unban(user=users.user)
                await ctx.channel.send(f"Unbanned: **{users.user}** Reason: **{users.reason}**")

            except:
                pass
            
        if (reason3==users.reason):
            
            try:
                await ctx.guild.unban(user=users.user)
                await ctx.channel.send(f"Unbanned: **{users.user}** Reason: **{users.reason}**")

            except:
                pass

        if (reason4==users.reason):
            
            try:
                await ctx.guild.unban(user=users.user)
                await ctx.channel.send(f"Unbanned: **{users.user}** Reason: **{users.reason}**")

            except:
                pass

    await ctx.channel.send(f"*Finished.*")
    print('Finished.')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).